# alter column type from bytea to timestamp with data retention in a Postgres Database

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-postgresql

The field in the java class looked like this :

```
private LocalDateTime updateTime;
```

However, Hibernate stores it in the database like this:

```
(output of "select update_time from my_table;")

ac  ed  00  05  73  72  00  1b  6f  72  67  2e  6a  6f  64  61  2e  74  69  6d  65  2e  4c  6f  63  61  6c  44  61  74  65  54  69  6d  65  fc  45  53  6c  f5  a5  87  10  02  00  02  4a  00  0c  69  4c  6f  63  61  6c  4d  69  6c  6c  69  73  4c  00  0b  69  43  68  72  6f  6e  6f  6c  6f  67  79  74  00  1a  4c  6f  72  67  2f  6a  6f  64  61  2f  74  69  6d  65  2f  43  68  72  6f  6e  6f  6c  6f  67  79  3b  78  70  00  00  01  42  09  8e  35  21  73  72  00  27  6f  72  67  2e  6a  6f  64  61  2e  74  69  6d  65  2e  63  68  72  6f  6e  6f  2e  49  53  4f  43  68  72  6f  6e  6f  6c  6f  67  79  24  53  74  75  62  a9  c8  11  66  71  37  50  27  03  00  00  78  70  73  72  00  1f  6f  72  67  2e  6a  6f  64  61  2e  74  69  6d  65  2e  44  61  74  65  54  69  6d  65  5a  6f  6e  65  24  53  74  75  62  a6  2f  01  9a  7c  32  1a  e3  03  00  00  78  70  77  05  00  03  55  54  43  78  78
```

Now we decided to change the java code to look like:

```
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
private LocalDateTime updateTime;
```

So that the value in the database looks like

```
(output of "select update_time from my_table;")
2013-12-18 00:00:00.0
```

However, the database table already has some values in this column. **How can we now convert the datatype of update_time to timestamp so that the existing values are also correctly handled?**

The database version and dependencies used are as below:
database version:

```
psql --version
psql (EnterpriseDB) 9.1.6.10
```

mvn dependencies for hibernate:

```
              <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1.Final</version>

                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.0.Final</version>

                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1.Final</version>

                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0.Final</version>

                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
```

Really stuck here. Any idea how can this be achieved? Any help here is truly appreciated.

Comment: You're not getting much response because (I think) nobody knows what that string of hex values is. If you can translate that into something that can form a valid timestamp then it's pretty straightforward from SQL. If not, presumably you'll have to (1) read all the bytea values and (2) separate them into textual timestamps and Java-object-internals timestamp then (3) save them back as all textual timestamps and THEN convert them all into real timestamps.

Comment: That string of hex values is translated into LocalDate when I use hibernate to fetch that field in my java code

Comment: If that's the only way you have to translate them, you'll have to read them in to your app, convert them to text and write them back.